# Stock Cost Price Calculation

Tags: stock, cost

Looking at this from an accouting side of things.

From what I can see a products cost price can only be one value but our suppliers put thier costs up every year so I could have the following situation

Product 1
year 1 Cost price £1 purchased 10 Sold 5  Stock Remaining 5 Year end value £5
year 2 Cost price £2 purchased 10 Sold 3  Stock Remaining 2 from Year 1 and 10  from year 2

What is my Cost price valuation
Latest cost 12 x £2 = 24
First in First Out  2 x £1 = 2  plus 10 x £2 = 20  which would be £22
Average Value 1.5 x 12 = 18

How do I capture these in Magento which seems to only have one field for cost price and at the end of the day I only want to enter the cost price into one place and not have mutiple spread sheets calcuating cost price.

Thanks

Ian